# How to find the expectation of the maximum of independent exponential variables?

Tags: probability, expected-value, exponential-distribution, order-statistics

Suppose $x_1, x_2, ......, x_n$ are i.i.d. random variable of exponential distribution $Exp(1)$, i.e., $f(x)=e^{-x}, x\gt0$.

Given the order statistics $x_{(1)} \le x_{(2)} \le......\le x_{(n)}$,
it is easy to find out that
$$F_{x(1)}(x)= 1 - \Big[1-F_{x}(x)\Big]^n = 1- \Big[1-(1-e^{-x})\Big]^n=1-e^{-nx}$$
$$F_{x(n)}(x) = \Big[F_{x}(x)\Big]^n = (1-e^{-x})^n$$
Taking the derivative,
$$f_{x(1)}(x) = ne^{-nx}$$
$$f_{x(n)}(x) = n(1-e^{-x})^{n-1}e^{-x}$$

Taking the integral, we have the expectation:
$$E(x_{(1)}) = \int_0^\infty xne^{-nx}dx = \int_0^\infty xn d\Big(-\frac{e^{-nx}}{n}\Big) = \Big[-xe^{-nx}\Big]_0^\infty + \int_0^\infty e^{-nx}dx=\frac{1}{n}$$

But how could I obtain the $E(x_{(n)})$, the expectation of the largest order statistic?

Comment: The full answer is on [StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/80485/14893), one Google click away...

Comment: I was trying to perform this, but the integral is $\int_0^\infty x n (1-e^{-x})^{n-1}e^{-x}dx$, and by Taylor expansion, $1-e^{-x} = x - \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{6} - \frac{x^4}{24} +......$, which is not obvious that its n-1th power is an explicit term.

Comment: Following the answer on the link I gave above$$\mathbb{E}[X_{(n)}]=\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{i}$$

Comment: Yeah by doing conditioning, by one thing is that $X_{(1)},X_{(n)}$ should be of special importance and I suppose there is a solution involving the Gamma function, which I believe gives a nicer formula, and the one you give will approach to ln(n), but is not a closed form. Thank you very much though.

Comment: Given that the expectation quoted by @Xi'an is correct, you're just going to have to live with it.  It's senseless to ask for a different answer just because the right answer isn't expressed in a way you like!  If you prefer, you may write it as $H(n)$, [which has a closed analytic expression.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html)

Comment: Wolfram can calculate  Integrate[x*n*(1 - Exp[-x])^(n - 1) Exp[-x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> {n > 1}]. The answer is HarmonicNumber[n] and this is the same as @Xi'an said

Comment: Really appreciate the efforts Wolfram put into integration, it solves a lot of unattainable integrations. I also tried integration by part, using much time actually, tackling the binomial coefficients, and it works as well. Maybe it worths to write out the step-by-step proof on some book's appendix since I may say no book ever provides a formal proof for it.

Comment: Method of moments makes the integral for x(n) trivial.

Comment: @Wayne It would be interesting to see how you apply MM to this problem.

Comment: Also specifically discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3560742/321264.

Answer (score 8):

The answer referenced in the comments is great, because it is based on straightforward probabilistic thinking.  But it is possible to obtain the answer through elementary means, beginning from definitions.

Because $x_{(n)}$ is the largest of $n$ independent variables, the event $x_{(n)}\le x$ is the event that all the $x_i \le x.$  Stipulating the $x_i$ have Exponential$(1)$ distributions says that for $x\gt 0,$ these have common probability $1 - e^{-x}$ (and otherwise have zero probability).

Since probabilities of independent events multiply,

$$\Pr(x_{(n)} \le x) = \left(1 - e^{-x}\right)^n.$$

One well-known formula for the expectation of a positive random variable with distribution function $F$ is the integral of $1-F$ from $0$ to $\infty.$   (Take the usual integral for the expectation and integrate by parts.) We are looking, then, to compute

$$E_n = E\left[x_{(n)}\right] = \int_0^\infty 1 - \left(1 - e^{-x}\right)^n\,\mathrm{d}x$$

for $n=1, 2, 3, \ldots.$

That initial "$1$" in the integrand is thorny, because its integral diverges, so we cannot separate it out.  However, **the *differences* between these quantities are considerably simpler to compute** because the $1$'s cancel:

$$E_{n} - E_{n-1} =  \int_0^\infty 1 - \left(1 - e^{-x}\right)^n - \left[1 - \left(1 - e^{-x}\right)^{n-1}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\infty \left(1 - e^{-x}\right)^{n-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

This is a textbook case for integration by substitution: the natural form to try is $u = 1-e^{-x},$ reducing the integral to

$$E_{n} - E_{n-1} = -\int_1^0 u^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{n}.$$

Beginning with $E_0=\int (1-1)\mathrm{d}x = 0,$ we obtain recursively

$$\begin{aligned}E_n &= E_0 + (E_1 - E_0) + (E_2 - E_1) + \cdots + (E_n - E_{n-1}) \\&= 0 + \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} = H(n),
\end{aligned}$$

the $n^\text{th}$ harmonic number.

Answer (score 5):

**Method of Moments approach**

Given a set of $n$ exponentially distributed i.i.d variables $X_i \sim EXP(1)$ the expected value of an ordered statistic $X_{i:n}$ is found in a straighforward fashion with the method of moments which gives the expected value as,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}[b]
E[X] = \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int e^{xt}f(x) \right]_{t=0}=  \int xf(x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Now, for the sake of rigor and clarity, consider the full pdf of the ordered statistic for a general integer $i ; 1<i< n$;

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}[b]
f(x_i) &= \frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!}[F(x_i)]^{i-1}[1-F(x_i)]^{n-i}f(x_i)   \\
&=\frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!}[1-e^{-x_i}]^{i-1}[e^{-x_i}]^{(n-i+1)x_i}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Applying the method of moments gives,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}[b]
E[X] &= \frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int [1-e^{-x_i}]^{i-1}[e^{-x_i}]^{(n-i+1-t)x_i}\right]_{t=0}\\
& = \frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!}\left[ \frac{(i-1)!(n-i)!}{n!}  \sum_{k=1}^i \frac{1}{n-k-t+1}  \right]_{t=0}\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^i \frac{1}{n-t+1} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

If I recall correctly in my messing around I found this method works well for the variance too, but I ran into difficulties in attempting to make it work for the covariance, e.g. $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1\partial t_2}e^{x_{i:n}t_1 + x_{j:n}t_2}f(x_{i:n},x_{j:n})$, but to no avail.  There might be some esoteric covariance formula for ordered statistics which makes it work though.

**Substitution approach**

Following a paper entitled *ORDER STATISTICS OF UNIFORM, LOGISTIC AND EXPONENTIAL DISTRIBUTIONS* by Okoyo Collins and Omondi (see page 100-102) an alternative is to make a clever substitution;

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}[b]
Z_i = (n-i+1)(X_i - X_{i-1}) \qquad \longrightarrow \qquad  X_i = \frac{Z_i}{n-i+1} + X_{i-1}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

which can be used to show that,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}[b]
X_i \sim \frac{Z_1}{n} + \frac{Z_2}{n-1} +...+ \frac{Z_i}{n-i+1}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

The Jacobian of the transformation turns out to be $n!$ (see pg 101 of referenced paper). Also, we conveniently have,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \sum_{i=1}^n z_i
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

(Convince yourself of this). The joint pdf then transforms as,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}[b]
f_{X_1,X_2,...,X_n} = n!e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i } \quad \longrightarrow \quad e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n z_i }
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Writing the subscripts out in full ordered notation, we now have,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}[b]
E[X_{i:n}] &= E\left[\frac{Z_{1:n}}{n} + \frac{Z_{2:n}}{n-1} +...+ \frac{Z_{i:n}}{n-i+1}\right]
&= \sum_{k=1}^i \frac{1}{n-t+1} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Because $Z_{i:n} \sim EXP(1)$ as well (?). This warrants additional justification, but I've taken it as far as needed for my purposes which was applied to a different problem.

Comment: +1 Thank you for sharing these answers.  The "method of moments" usually refers to a procedure for *estimating* distributions based on sample moments.  The first method you give is usually known as the "moment generating function" approach.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach is that we can view the order statistic as a sum statistic. An explanation is given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4283180

If $X_k \sim Exp(1)$ then

$$max(X_1, X_2, \dots , X_n) \qquad \sim \qquad \sum_{k=1}^n Y_k$$

with $Y_k \sim Exp(n+1-k)$.

And then you can compute the expectation value as

$$E\left[max(X_1, X_2, \dots , X_n)\right] = E\left[\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k\right] = \sum_{k=1}^n E\left[Y_k\right] = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+1-k} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} $$

---

In general you get for the $m$-th order statistic (of $n$ exponential distributed variables) the expectation:

$$E[X_{(k)}] = \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{n+1-k} $$