# Expected value of maximum of $n$ iid exponential random variables

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution, extreme-value

I was recently playing around with this distribution. Let $Y_n \sim \max_i X_i$ where $X_i \sim \exp(\lambda)$. Then the well-known result
$$ f_{Y_n}(y) = \lambda n e^{-\lambda y}(1-e^{-\lambda y})^{n-1}, \ y \ge 0.  $$
I've seen results for the mean of this distribution when $n = 2,3$ but not in general. I derived the following result and was wondering if this was known and if it could be simplified any further?
\begin{align}
E(Y_n) & = \int_0^\infty \lambda n y e^{-\lambda y}(1 - e^{-\lambda y})^{n-1} \ dy \\
& = -n \frac{\partial}{\partial c}\bigg |_{c=1} \int_0^\infty e^{-c \lambda y}(1 - e^{-\lambda y})^{n-1} \ dy, \quad \text{let } u = e^{-\lambda y} \\
& = -n \frac{\partial}{\partial c}\bigg |_{c=1} \int_1^0 x^c (1 - x)^{n-1} \ \left(-\frac{dx}{\lambda x} \right) \\
& = \frac{n}{\lambda} \frac{\partial}{\partial c}\bigg |_{c=1} \int_1^0 x^{c-1} (1 - x)^{n-1} \ dx \\
& = -\frac{n}{\lambda} \frac{\partial}{\partial c}\bigg |_{c=1} \beta(c,n),
\end{align}
where
$$\beta(c,n) = \frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(c+n)}.$$
In particular - can we approximate the derivative when $n \approx 1$ or $n\gg 1$?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/324274/119261

Comment: Neat! Thanks. So basically my expression is equivalent to a particular sum of harmonic numbers?

Comment: This can be expressed in terms of the digamma function.  The analysis very closely follows the one I recently presented at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/560967/919.

Comment: @whuber always a pleasure to read your answers. Cheers.